# Applescript keystroke fails

Tags: applescript

I have a problem with my application, I want AppleScript to type "date" in Terminal:

```
(
    activate application "Terminal"
    tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "date"
    keystroke return
    end tell
)
```

It works, but if the language of my keyboard is set to Russian, my app types "####" instead of "date". How to make AppleScript always use the English keyboard mapping?

Comment: Sorry, can't help you with Russian/English issue. Why are you using System Events and `keystroke`? Just use Terminal's `do script` command, e.g. `tell application "Terminal" to do script "date"`

Comment: Thanks, but... For ex. I need to write my system password (f.ex. "qwerty").. It transforms to "йцуке"...

Answer (score 0):

If you have to send a string to the cursor/insertion point, you can avoid the keystroke command by storing the string on the clipboard and then pasting it.

```
tell application "Terminal" to activate
set theString to "date"
set the clipboard to theString
delay 0.1
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Terminal"
        tell menu bar item "Edit" of menu bar 1
            click menu item "Paste" of menu 1
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
delay 0.1
```

You should also explore sending a command to the terminal window as a command. Tell a Terminal window to do script.

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    set thisWindow to do script "echo 'hello world'" in window 1
    do script "echo 'goodbye all'" in thisWindow
end tell
```

You didn't give enough details of what you're doing to know how best to solve your problem.